# input type button to change focus on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input type button which is red. I have used CSS to change the color of the button to blue when hovered on. If the tab button is used and it reaches the input button it should change to green. I did this with focus in CSS but when I press enter it still remains green but I want it to go back to red again as it was initially. Basically, I want to remove the focus after pressing enter.

I have tried this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0"> <input id=" car" class="button calculator large top-right-border transition" type="submit" /> </div>
```

Comment: <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
                <input id=" car" class="button calculator large top-right-border transition" type="submit"  />
            </div>

Comment: Please let us know some of your code make a fiddle

Comment: @abhi Don't write in comments.write in question whatever you have tried. otherwise you will get downvotes here.

Comment: can someone please answer I am new here

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file

```
#car { background-color: red; }
#car:focus { background-color: green; }
```

With jQuery, in the document ready function, add a handler to the click event for the input. ie:

```
$(function() {
     $('#car').click(function() { 
         // Unfocus from the input when it's clicked
         $(this).blur();
     });
});
```

This will unfocus from the button, returning the css to the "non-focus" class

Comment: yes I have tried this and I want that when you press enter key on the button then it should come back to its original color

Comment: I want that when I am in focus and press enter it should change its color back to original that is from green to red

Comment: yes jquery javascript html and css whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this might work for you - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/mc9t19jm/).

JS

```
var $mybutton = $('#mybutton');

$mybutton.on('focus', function(){
                                 $mybutton.css('background-color', 'green');
                                 });

$mybutton.on('blur', function(){
                                $mybutton.css('background-color', 'red');
                                });

$mybutton.hover( 
                function(){
                           $mybutton.css('background-color', 'blue');
                           },
                function(){
                           $mybutton.css('background-color', 'red');
                           }
);
```

Or just CSS:

```
#mybutton {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
#mybutton:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
#mybutton:focus {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```